# Simple solution to share modules loaded via NPM across multiple Browserify or Webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, webpack

Pulling my hair out here looking for a *simple* solution to share code, required via NPM, across multiple Browserify or Webpack bundles.  Thinking, is there such a thing as a file "bridge"?

This isn't due to compile time (I'm aware of watchify) but rather the desire to extract out all of my vendor specific libs into `vendor.js` so to keep my `app.js` filesize down and to not crash the browser with massive sourcemaps.  Plus, I find it way cleaner should the need to view the compiled js arise.  And so:

```
// vendor.js

require('react');
require('lodash');
require('other-npm-module');
require('another-npm-module');
```

Its very important that the code be loaded from NPM as opposed to Bower, or saved into some 'vendor' directory in order to be imported via a relative path and identified via a shim.  I'd like to keep every library reference pulled via NPM except for my actual application source.

In `app.js` I keep all of my sourcecode, and via the `externals` array, exclude vendor libraries listed above from compilation:

```
// app.js 

var React = require('react');
var _     = require('lodash');

var Component = React.createClass()

// ...
```

And then in `index.html`, I require both files

```
// index.html
<script src='vendor.js'></script>
<script src='app.js'></script>
```

Using Browserify or Webpack, how can I make it so that `app.js` can "see" into those module loaded via npm?  I'm aware of creating a bundle with externals and then referencing the direct file (in, say, `node_modules`) via an alias, but I'm hoping to find a solution that is more automatic and less "Require.js" like.

Basically, I'm wondering if it is possible to bridge the two so that `app.js` can look inside `vendor.js` in order to resolve dependencies.  This seems like a simple, straightforward operation but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere on this wide, wide web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With webpack you'd use multiple entry points and the [CommonChunkPlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin).

Taken from the [webpack docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code):

---

To split your app into 2 files, say `app.js` and `vendor.js`, you can require the vendor files in `vendor.js`. Then pass this name to the CommonChunkPlugin as shown below.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./app.js",
    vendor: ["jquery", "underscore", ...],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
        /* chunkName= */"vendor",
        /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.js"
    )
  ]
};
```

This will remove all modules in the vendor chunk from the app chunk. The `bundle.js` will now contain just your app code, without any of it’s dependencies. These are in `vendor.bundle.js`.

In your HTML page load `vendor.bundle.js` before `bundle.js`.

```
<script src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

---

Comment: I assume react goes in the vendor array too?

Comment: are you just including the name of the vendor file in that array, or should it be a path to it?

Comment: I don't want to make a separate bundle or chunk for my separate library of components I'm sharing between projects, I just want to require the source files directly.  Do you know a way to do this? (full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820641/how-to-set-up-a-private-shared-library-of-react-components-with-webpack)

Comment: what if i don't know what the vendor array's content is? 'cause it may be dynamically changed, is there any way auto-collecting third-party dependencies and putting them into a seperate bundle?

Answer (score 26):

Listing all the vendor files/modules and using [CommonChunkPlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin) is indeed the recommended way. This gets pretty tedious though, and error prone.

Consider these NPM modules: `fastclick` and `mprogress`. Since they have not adopted the [CommonJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) module format, you need to give webpack a hand, like this:

```
require('imports?define=>false!fastclick')(document.body);
require('mprogress/mprogress.min.css');
var Mprogress = require('mprogress/mprogress.min.js'),
```

Now assuming you would want both  `fastclick` and `mprogress` in your vendor chunk, you would probably try this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./app.js",
    vendor: ["fastclick", "mprogress", ...]
```

Alas, it doesn't work. You need to match the calls to `require()`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./app.js",
    vendor: [
      "imports?define=>false!fastclick", 
      "mprogress/mprogress.min.css", 
      "mprogress/mprogress.min.js", 
      ...]
```

It gets old, even with some `resolve.alias` trickery. Here is my workaround. CommonChunkPlugin lets you specify a callback that will return whether or not you want a module to be included in the vendor chunk. If your own source code is in a specific `src` directory, and the rest is in the `node_modules` directory, just reject the modules based on their path:

```
var node_modules_dir = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    app_dir          = path.join(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./app.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
      /* chunkName= */"vendor",
      /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.js"
      function (module, count) {
       return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(app_dir) === -1;
      }
    )
  ]
};
```

Where `module.resource` is the path to the module being considered. You could also do the opposite, and include only the module if it is inside `node_modules_dir`, i.e.:

```
       return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(node_modules_dir) === 0;
```

but in my situation, I'd rather say: "*put everything that is not in my source source tree in a vendor chunk*".

Hope that helps.

Comment: is the `./app.js` file in the `src` directory?

Comment: also, how does this work where you have npm modules that you use for development but don't want in a production vendor file? for example, say you had `Backbone.js` and `underscore.js` as  `node_module`s, which you need in the vendor file, but also have other `node_modules` that were only included for dev purposes and you don't want bundled in a `vendor.bundle.js`

Comment: @Leahcim it looks like a decision that you need to make when you load the "dev only" modules, not in the webpack.config file. You could use something like the `DefinePlugin` to define a `IS_DEV` and conditionally require your dev node_modules.. then if you compile when `IS_DEV` is false, it won't get loaded in the first place

Comment: Thanks @sebastien.b.  Your CommonsChunkPlugin callback solution worked for me, although your syntax looks a little off.  There should be a comma before the callback function, and I don't know what that "minChunks:" label is doing there at all.

Is the CommonsChunkPlugin callback in the doco anywhere?  I couldn't see it.

Comment: I edited the answer and removed the `minChunks` label.

Answer (score 0):

```
// vendor anything coming from node_modules
minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource)
```

Source: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2372#issuecomment-213149173