# Webpack workflow splitting vendor and app code efficiently

Tags: javascript, npm, workflow, gulp, webpack

I have had trouble finding sufficient Webpack documentation and examples to hash out an ideal dev workflow for my situation. Here are all the features that would make the workflow ideal:

1. Watching, ideally through Gulp, with efficient caching. (Don't think I need hot module replacement and suspect it might not fit into my dev environment well.)
2. Vendor modules (right now I have only npm packages, not all of them exposing UMD globals in their main file, if it came down to that) that are

   a. not parsed & re-compiled during watch (so recompilation is faster),

   b. do not receive a sourcemap (so browser devtools are faster to respond), and

   c. write to a distinct `vendor.js` bundle that browsers can cache separately from app bundles.
3. App modules that are

   a. explicit about all dependencies (i.e. `import React from 'react';` even if React is actually globally exposed or something via #2),

   b. *are* re-compiled during watch, and

   c. *do* receive a sourcemap.

Most of what I have read in documentation or examples has not seemed to hit this workflow on the head.

While I do see in the docs how to create a vendor-specific bundle (reproduced here: [Simple solution to share modules loaded via NPM across multiple Browserify or Webpack bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603499/simple-solution-to-share-modules-loaded-via-npm-across-multiple-browserify-or-we/26628468#26628468)), the simple example provided does not address 2a and 2b.

I don't see in the docs any ways to specify different compile-configurations (sourcemaps, etc.) for different chunks, or to create completely separate Webpack bundles with separate config files that can reference each other, unless by globalizing all vendor libraries and using them as externals (?), which isn't ideal ...

Also, I am curious whether Gulp users are using `gulp-webpack` or instead a setup like that provided in http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html. (I'm not sure how well the `webpack-dev-server` would fit into my dev environment so would like to stick to `gulp-watch` if possible.)

Am I missing something that other Webpack users know about? What's the best way to do this?

*OR* is it possible that Webpack is not the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Watching, ideally through Gulp, with efficient caching. (Don't think I need hot module replacement and suspect it might not fit into my dev environment well.)

Use [webpack-dev-server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html).

You don't really need Gulp for this but you can use its Node API with Gulp (I'm doing that).

> Vendor modules (right now I have only npm packages, not all of them exposing UMD globals in their main file, if it came down to that) that are
>
> a. not parsed & re-compiled during watch (so recompilation is faster),

I don't think unchanged files would be parsed or recompiled during watch.

> b. do not receive a sourcemap (so browser devtools are faster to respond), and

Don't know how to do this one. I think source maps are either all in or all out. But you can use `devtool: 'eval'` which works much faster than source maps.

> c. write to a distinct vendor.js bundle that browsers can cache separately from app bundles.

I think you're looking for [split-by-name-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/soundcloud/split-by-name-webpack-plugin#how).

> App modules that are
>
> a. explicit about all dependencies (i.e. import React from 'react'; even if React is actually globally exposed or something via #2),

This will work. To `require` globally exposed libraries, use [`externals` config option](http://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html#applications-and-externals).

> b. are re-compiled during watch, and

What has changed, will be recompiled (if you use webpack-dev-server).

This doesn't answer all your questions but I hope it's enough to figure out whether this works for you. I don't think “not watching libraries” is such a big issue as you say it is (there's very little perf penalty on rebuilding cached modules) and if you ditch sourcemaps and use `devtool: 'eval'`, I'd say it's really fast. Finally, [there's a new watching solution in the works for Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/125) so you might want to give it a spin. It should have even better perf.

Comment: You have suggestions for the important points -- thanks.

The only part that bothers me, a response that I've seen a lot from other Webpack users, is the terse "Use webpack-dev-server." Gulp seems to me to be a much more flexible and robust tool for task running, building, watching, etc., than Webpack, so I'm sticking with it. I do think that one serious downside of Webpack is that it wants to create another "ecosystem" instead of integrating well with what already exists. Thanks again.

Comment: @davidtheclark Gulp is just a task runner. You should at least give `webpack-dev-server` a try, it uses Webpack's watch mode which means fast incremental rebuilds. There's a severe downside to trying to replicate this behavior with Gulp and gulp-watch because they can't tell Webpack which modules changed. Also you'll be missing out on hot module reloading (although as you said it's not a priority for you). Webpack dev server is trivial to wrap in a Gulp task though.

Comment: "Gulp seems to me to be a much more flexible and robust tool for task running, building, watching". I don't think it's a fair comparison. One is a generic task runner, another is a JS bundler. They solve different problems and can work together.