# How to set up a private shared library of React components with Webpack

Tags: module, npm, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I have a number of React components that I use in multiple Webpack projects, and I want to share them via NPM.  So naturally I:

1. put those components into a (private) GitHub repo
2. Added that repo to a main project's `package.json`
3. So that I could develop on the component library simultaneously, I used `npm link` to symlink it into my main project.

However, Webpack can't resolve `react` from my library component files, because there's no `node_modules` in the library project folder or any of its parents.

I've seen 3rd party React components that were built as a bundle with `react` in the `externals` of the Webpack config, but I don't want to build a separate bundle or do anything complicated, I just want to require the raw source for my library components.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could find a more elegant solution, but adding this to my `webpack.config.js` worked:

```
resolve: {
    fallback: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
},
resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") },
```

However, I ultimately decided it would be easier just to share the components between projects in a git submodule.